# AdMob Mediation - passing multiple adapters to AdRequest

Tags: android, admob, mobile-ad-mediation

Does anybody use a several mediation adapters with AdMob in Android?
I haven't found any samples in such case. I don't know if it's a correct way to pass a several adapters to AdRequest.Builder via *addNetworkExtrasBundle*  function.

```
AdRequest.Builder adReqBuilder = new AdRequest.Builder();
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putBoolean("tag_for_under_age_of_consent", true);
extras.putString("npa", "1");   // non personalized ads

adReqBuilder.addNetworkExtrasBundle(AdMobAdapter.class, extras); // Why I need also to pass AdMobAdapter???
adReqBuilder.addNetworkExtrasBundle(UnityAdapter.class, extras);
adReqBuilder.addNetworkExtrasBundle(FacebookAdapter.class, extras);
```